# Chatter Newsfeed in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, chatter-feed

I am using the  tag on my vf page but the edit buttons expand by default.

[image: newsfeed]

Has anyone encountered the same issue? How do I collapse the buttons as how it should normally display?

Thanks!

Comment: I have used it fine on visualforce pages. Do you have any css styles on the page that may be conflicting with the standard styles?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have css styles and that did cause the problem on the chatter display. My workaround was to create a separate vf page containing only the chatter feed then use it as a template on the main vf page and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer and accept it to close this thread?

Answer (score 1):

Pls check other CSS files in your page that may be conflicting with the standard styles. [copied from comment]